# What is the correct way to create an object which has both belongs_to and validates_presence_of validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to

I would like to create an object which both validates the presence of a parent object AND validates the validity of the parent object. However I would like to create it independently of the parent object and I'm not sure how to do so.

This is my code:

```
class User
  has_many :questions
end

class Question
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_associated :user
end
```

**I know I can do this:**

```
u = User.create
q = u.questions.create
```

**but I need to do this**

```
u = User.create
q = Question.create(:user_id => u.id)

q.valid? 
=> false

q.errors?
=> <OrderedHash {:user=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

**What is the correct way to deal with this?**

Should I use

```
 class User 
 ...
   before(:save) do
     self.user = User.find(self.user_id)
   end

 end
```

This seems unnecessarily messy - is there a better way?

Comment: Peter, I'm curious if the User object is created & saved prior to being referenced by the new Question object. Also, why create vs. new? Is this a requirement of the applicatoin or just shorthand?

Comment: Nuby, I'm just using 'create' as shorthand. I think that it is created and saved before being referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should maybe use `validates_the_presence_of :user_id` in the Question Model instead of `validates_presence_of :user`.

I hope it would help.

Comment: I'm going to create a custom validator instead so that I can confirm the presence of the user_id and the validity of the user. It still feels like I'm missing something but this was useful to get going with

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to create the object through a form? If you are then I would suggest using the build method and accepts_nested_attributes - this will allow you to create both the parent object and a child object at the same time. I usually reference [Ryan's post](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) when wanting to do this.

Comment: It's not for form creation unfortunately and it's actually for a more complex question (an object with two parent dependencies). The reason I'm asking it in this way is that it's the simplest subset of the main problem I have